# To generate mobile app in magento using mofluid

Tags: magento-1.9

i already configured mofluid to my magento(1.9 ver) local host,but the problem is while creating android mobile app it's showing "localhost or local IPs are not allowed. please use Mofluid with Staging or Production Environment." How to resolve this things.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with mofluid, but it looks like its a hosted platform, so localhost would never be reachable. You have two approaches that you could take depending on your internet service.

Ask your service provider for a static IP, and configure your router to send traffic (port 80) to the internal IP of your computer then use the public static IP in place of localhost.

Alternatively (better solution):
Setup hosting on a server which is accessible by the internet and use the IP of this machine instead of your local one.

Comment: Thank u for ur suggestion..